# Error 13 VBA, Trying to insert an image to ppt/Trying to use an already existing ppt

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have searched for an answer but came up empty, so I post in hopes that this is fixable.

I have numbers, charts, and arrays in an excel file, and I want to export them to a given powerpoint file.

I cannot get to open the powerpoint I want, so I have to create a new one. And I can't get the image to be inserted into the new file. I get an error 13, incompatibility. (the set oPic line is throwing the error)

The VBA script is in Excel.

This is what I have

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPPT()
Dim PPT As Object
Dim MyPres As Object
Dim MySlide As Slide
Dim myShape As Shape
Dim oPic As Shape

Dim icount As Integer
Dim file As String

file = "C:\Users\Amandine\Desktop\RapportsAuto\Client_Date.pptm"

Set Rng = Worksheets("Setup").Range("Nom_PG")

On Error Resume Next
Set PPT = GetObject(file, class:="PowerPoint.Application")
Err.Clear
If PPT Is Nothing Then Set PPT = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set MyPres = PPT.Presentations.Add
Set MySlide = MyPres.Slides.Add(1, 11)
Set oPic = MyPres.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Amandine\Desktop\RapportsAuto\ImagePG.png", False, True, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code and successfully tested that it works as follows:

```
Option Explicit

' Runs in Excel VBE so a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint XX Object Library is required for Early Binding
' To use the more reliable Late Binding, change the PowerPoint.XYZ object types to "Object" and remove the reference above
Sub ExcelRangeToPPT()
  ' Late Binding PowerPoint objects
  Dim oPPT As Object
  ' Early Binding PowerPoint objects
  Dim oPres As PowerPoint.Presentation ' Object
  Dim oSld As PowerPoint.Slide ' Object
  Dim oShp As PowerPoint.Shape ' Object
  Dim oPic As PowerPoint.Shape ' Object
  Dim oLayout As PowerPoint.CustomLayout ' Object
  ' Excel objects
  Dim oRng As Range

  Dim iCount As Integer
  Dim sFile As String

  Const sPath = "C:\Users\Amandine\Desktop\RapportsAuto\"

  sFile = sPath & "Client_Date.pptm"

  Set oRng = Worksheets("Setup").Range("Nom_PG")

  On Error Resume Next
  Set oPPT = GetObject(sFile, "PowerPoint.Application")
  Err.Clear
  If oPPT Is Nothing Then Set oPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
      'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
          MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
          Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set oPres = oPPT.Presentations.Add
  Set oLayout = oPres.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(11)
  Set oSld = oPres.Slides.AddSlide(1, oLayout)
  Set oPic = oPres.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture(sPath & "ImagePG.png", False, True, 0, 0, 1, 1)

  ' Do other actions

  ' Clear Up
  Set oPres = Nothing
  Set oLayout = Nothing
  Set oSld = Nothing
  Set oPic = Nothing
  Set oShp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know what late or early binding mean. The line throwing the error is the adding picture one (sorry, I should have mentionned that in the post)

Comment: it doesn't recognise .AddSlide it throws an error (error 13)

Comment: Which version of Office are you using?

Comment: I took your code, modified it as above and tested that it works with Office 2013. I also added a brief explanation about Early/Late Binding which is definitely something any cross-application developer should understand when writing VBA that uses more that one core Office app library.

Comment: Thank you, for that and the explanation, I will try it as soon as I get my computer back